# clear: both doesn't prevent wrapping

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have 3 divs: 2 of them are floating (to left and right), and the 3rd should be placed under the two others. I used `clear: both` to do that but its not working at all!

http://jsfiddle.net/uYrPY/1/

CSS

```
.left, .right {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.left {float: left;}
.right {float: right;}
.bottom {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="left">
</div>
<div class="right">
</div>
<div class="bottom">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/fLe5n/

Comment: Don't give any space in `clear` and `both`: clear:both;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a non-breaking space between "clear:" and "both" in your [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uYrPY/1/), remove it and it will work fine!

http://jsfiddle.net/uYrPY/2/

```
 .left, .right {
    width: 50px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
.left {float: left;}
.right {float: right;}
.bottom {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Impressive.. How did you spot that?

Comment: Thanks to sublime text...I get the same thing all the time (which is pretty annoying as you can guess)